# What is the connection of correlation between variables to decision tree feature importance

Tags: correlation, feature-selection, cart

I am using decision tree regression to predict a variable.
I realized that the highest correlating features to my target variable are not the ones I get returned with a high feature importance.
Something I didnt expect. How to interpret this?

Thanks

Comment: You mean the correlation between your individual features and the target?

Comment: Yes. Comparing to the feature importance in DTR of the respective features.